# Can it be show geometrically the cross product is the area of a parallelogram and is perpendicular to the crossed vectors?

Tags: geometry, cross-product

I found  similar questions but they did not exactly derive the area of a parallelogram using the definition and at the same time show the cross product vector must necessarily be perpendicular.   ( As a side note I assume this new vector has to lie at point joining the crossed vectors but I cannot understand how any proof can demand this but somehow this must be the case by necessity. )  Maybe too much to ask.  A one stop shop proof of all the details so one does not have to look in bits and pieces of the proof in multiple textbooks may be too much to ask for.

Comment: How do you define the cross product in the first place? Some versions of the definition start with the area of the spanned parallelogram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take the algebraic definition of the cross product to be
$$ (a \times b)_i = \sum_{j,k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk} a_j b_k, $$
where $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is the Levi-Civita symbol, defined to be $0$ when two of $i,j,k$ are equal, $1$ when $ijk$ is one of $123,231,312$ and $-1$ when $ijk$ is one of $213,132,321$ (the nonzero cases being respectively even and odd permutations of $123$). In particular, $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is totally antisymmetric, in that swapping any two of $i,j,k$ returns the negative of the original value:
$$ \epsilon_{ijk} = \epsilon_{jki} = \epsilon_{kij} = -\epsilon_{jik} = -\epsilon_{ikj} = -\epsilon_{kji}. $$
This gives the familiar $(a\times b)_1 = a_2b_3-b_3a_2 $ and so on.

With this definition, it is also clear that $a \times b$ is perpendicular to $a$ and $b$:
$$ a \cdot (a\times b) = \sum_{i,j,k=1}^3 \epsilon_{ijk} a_ia_j b_k = 0 $$
since $a_ia_j$ is symmetric and $\epsilon_{ijk}$ antisymmetric when we swap $i$ and $j$.

Lastly, we would like to find the magnitude and direction. We suppose $a,b \neq 0$ for obvious nontriviality reasons. We can actually find both using the same formula: three vectors form a right-handed basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if the determinant of the matrix with them as columns is positive:
$$ \det \begin{pmatrix} a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\ a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\ a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} > 0  $$
But this determinant is
$$ \sum_{i,j,k} \epsilon_{ijk} a_i b_j c_k = (a \times b) \cdot c. $$
So if $c=a \times b$, the determinant is $\lVert a \times b \rVert^2 > 0 $. So the determinant is positive, and thus $a \times b$ is the third vector of a right-handed basis with first two elements $a$ and $b$.

To actually calculate this, we need the following identity:
$$ (a \times b) \times c = -a(b \cdot c) + b(a \cdot c). $$
This can be proven using my favourite $\epsilon$ identity:
$$ \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmn} = \det\begin{pmatrix} \delta_{il} & \delta_{im} & \delta_{in} \\
\delta_{jl} & \delta_{jm} & \delta_{jn} \\
\delta_{kl} & \delta_{km} & \delta_{kn}
\end{pmatrix} $$
The proof is rather unenlightening, unfortunately: both sides are zero if two of the indices on one $\epsilon$ are equal (and two rows of the determinant are equal), the symmetries of the left and right-hand sides are the same by the properties of determinants, and then one can just check on one set of indices. But this also means, by expansion, that
$$ \sum_k \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kmn} = \delta_{im} \delta_{jn} - \delta_{in} \delta_{jm}. $$
But then
$$ (a \times b) \cdot (a \times b) = \sum_{i,j,k,m,n}\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kmn} a_ib_j a_m d_n = (a \cdot a)(b \cdot b) - (a\cdot b)^2 = \lVert a \rVert^2\lVert b\rVert^2(1-\cos^2{\theta}) = \lVert a \rVert^2\lVert b\rVert^2\sin^2{\theta},  $$
which is the other formula for the magnitude of the cross product; since the length is nonnegative and $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$, the sign of the square root is unambiguous.

Comment: I did not know that cross product was a special case of tensor analysis ...or is it a special case of exterior algebra?  This is all very interesting. It is a very rich animal. I am wondering if there are fewer steps possible to show the magnitude of the algebraic definition in the from of simple vector notation is in fact the area of a parallelogram and the vector of that magnitude is perpendicular to the two joining vectors used to form the definition.

Comment: It's both: the cross product is generalised by the wedge product, which can be thought of either as a geometric product, or an antisymmetric tensor product. That it only works in three dimensions should puzzle you until you see the link to being "the missing part" of a determinant, which has to be square. One doesn't have to do it this way (one can simply show the definition works), but any other way tends to involve line upon line of unenlightening algebra and suspiciously coincidental factorisations.

Comment: One could instead characterise it as an alternating bilinear map from vectors to vectors, which is sufficient to determine it up to a constant. (This also leans on the determinant idea, since the determinant is an alternating map on three vectors that returns a scalar; the cross product is in some sense dual to this.

Comment: And there's also the characterisation in terms of quaternion multiplication: given quaternions $a_0+\mathbf{a}$, $b_0+\mathbf{b}$, where $\mathbf{a}=a_1 i + a_2 j + a_3 k$ &c., $$ \mathbf{ab} = (a_0b_0-\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}) + (a_0 \mathbf{b}+b_0\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}). $$

Comment: You say "coincidental factorisations"   yes , key insight, alas that is what motivated the question to begin with

Comment: It's a matter of approach: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_four-square_identity looks miraculous until you interpret it as quaternion multiplication. Choosing the "right" definition in the first place is also crucial to having an easy life.

Answer (score 1):

One quick proof is to use an orthogonal transformation to assume that the vectors are $(a,0,0)$ and $(b,c,0)$ their cross product is then $(0,0,ac)$ which is orthogonal and $ac$ is the base times height of the parallelogram.

Comment: HaHa, well it took you 5 hours to respond, what are you stuck in amber ?

Comment: Love to see some more detail on this.